# Jasper Report JasperReportsPdfView SpringBoot Subreport error

Tags: java, spring-boot, jasper-reports

Report structure:

```
main report - myreport.jrxml 
sub report  - myreport_detail.jrxml
```

Running my main report with sub report works fine in Jasper Report Studio. In my Spring Boot environment I use JasperReportsPdfView.

However running myreport.jrxml here I get:

```
Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Resource not found at: jasper/repo/myreport_detail.jasper.
at net.sf.jasperreports.repo.RepositoryUtil.getResourceFromLocation(RepositoryUtil.java:153)
at net.sf.jasperreports.repo.RepositoryUtil.getReport(RepositoryUtil.java:112)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.loadReport(JRFillSubreport.java:411)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.evaluateReport(JRFillSubreport.java:378)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.evaluateSubreport(JRFillSubreport.java:440)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.evaluate(JRFillSubreport.java:354)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.evaluate(JRFillElementContainer.java:383)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.evaluate(JRFillBand.java:506)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnBand(JRVerticalFiller.java:2412)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillDetail(JRVerticalFiller.java:761)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:240)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:99)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:607)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseReportFiller.fill(BaseReportFiller.java:387)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:109)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:456)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:863)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.jasperreports.AbstractJasperReportsView.doFillReport(AbstractJasperReportsView.java:702)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.jasperreports.AbstractJasperReportsView.fillReport(AbstractJasperReportsView.java:669)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.jasperreports.AbstractJasperReportsView.renderMergedOutputModel(AbstractJasperReportsView.java:566)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1271)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1037)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:980)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
... 97 common frames omitted
```

Note: running one single report without sub report works fine

Endpoint:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/api", params = {"dir", "name"})
public ModelAndView report(
    HttpServletRequest request,
    @RequestParam(value = "dir") String dir,
    @RequestParam(value = "name") String name) throws Exception {

    JasperReportsPdfView view = new JasperReportsPdfView();
    view.setJdbcDataSource(dataSource);
    view.setUrl("classpath:jasper/" + dir + "/" + name + ".jrxml");
    view.setApplicationContext(context);
    view.setHeaders(getProperties(name, false));
    return new ModelAndView(view, getParameters(request));
}
```

Java code crash RepositoryUtil:

```
    public <K extends Resource> K getResourceFromLocation(String location, Class<K> resourceType) throws JRException
{
    K resource = null;
    List<RepositoryService> services = getServices();
    if (services != null)
    {
        for (RepositoryService service : services)
        {
            resource = service.getResource(location, resourceType);
            if (resource != null)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (resource == null)
    {
        throw 
        new JRException(
            EXCEPTION_MESSAGE_KEY_RESOURCET_NOT_FOUND,
            new Object[]{location});    //FIXMEREPO decide whether to return null or throw exception; check everywhere
    }
    return resource;
}
```

Error line:

```
    resource = service.getResource(location, resourceType);
```

Variable:

```
  location -> jasper/repo/myreport_detail.jasper
  resourceType -> class net.sf.jasperreports.repo.ReportResource
```

Exception line thrown because resource = null:

```
    public static final String EXCEPTION_MESSAGE_KEY_RESOURCET_NOT_FOUND = "repo.resource.not.found";
```

Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supplied the .jasper files and then it worked. Running one report only without sub report I did not need to supply them though:-) Thought they where generated on the fly in the Spring Boot environment.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as Jasper Studio problem that I had at 1 point. 
Try to check expression that you are using for sub-report in main report. Depending of version Jasper Report Studio expects sub-report to be defined as

`"folderOfyourSubReport/myreport_detail.jrxml"`

or

`"folderOfyourSubReport/myreport_detail.jasper"`

Comment: OK, but in Jasper Studio it works. But not in my SpringBoot environment. Currently they are in the same directory.